# Error -32 while establishing USB connection

Tags: usb, usb-device

We are working on a custom board based on STM32F769NI in Ubuntu 16.04 which has an FT232RL chip. We are connecting a micro USB cable from PC to custom board (micro USB port is adjacent to FT232RL chip in our board). When the USB cable is inserted, the following log appears:

[image: Terminal Log]

I read there is no need to install any ftdi drivers. In Windows 10 also, unknown device descriptor. There is no serial port in Ports is displayed.

[image: FT232RL Schematic]

lsusb is also displaying only keyboard and mouse only:

```
$ sudo lsusb
Terminal log : device not accepting address, error -32
Unable to enumerate USB device
```

Comment: Show your *complete* schematic.  You do not show what is driving the /RESET pin, and this is required to be high for the internal USB speed detection resistor to be activated on D+.

Comment: A possible answer could be this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340730/usb-device-enumeration-fails-device-descriptor-read-64-error-32#comment133860471_22342619

Answer (score 3):

This often happens when the power is unstable, the clock is fluctuating or imprecise, or the propagation delays in the cable or on the PCB are unacceptable.

With custom cables/boards, the reason is often that D+ and D- lines get connected in reverse. I see the computer reports FT232RL as a low-speed device, while I'd expect it to be a full-speed one.

For the record, the error -32 (`-EPIPE`) is described in [Linux kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/usb/error-codes.html) as follows:

> - The pipe type specified in the URB doesn't match the endpoint's actual type.
> - Endpoint stalled. For non-control endpoints, reset this status with usb_clear_halt().

Answer (score 1):

It is worth trying a powered USB hub to power your device rather than plugging straight into your PC. That could address some power issues.

Comment: I'm wondering why this was downvoted. It seems like it could possibly address the power issue brought up by @Dmitry Grigoryev above. I have run into scenarios like this in the past. I would have left a comment except that my reputation is not high enough yet.